# fire interaction by onClick(jquery)

Tags: jquery, grid, click

hey there i have this pic on my page:

```
<?php echo "<img src=\"image.php\" id=\"pic\" class=\"grid\">";?>
```

by clicking on this element, an interaction should be started so i tested:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#pic" ).click(function() {
        alert ( "Works" );
    });
});
```

works, next i wanted to implement an interaction ( http://jqueryui.com/resizable/#snap-to-grid )

this interaction should start only if you click on this image and exactly at this place, you click on, so:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#pic" ).click(function() {
        $( "#grid" ).resizable({
            grid: 20;
        });
    });
});
```

but it doesnt work, anybody knows why? greetings

Comment: Change the hashtag for an ID to a dot for a CLASS.Also, make sure you're calling your scripts after the DOM is loaded and that they're implementing both jquery and jqueryUI.

Answer (score 1):

You have used a selector id in `#grid`, but you have to elect the class grid in this mode: `.grid`
change this:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#pic" ).click(function() {
        $( "#grid" ).resizable({
            grid: 20;
        });
    });
});
```

to this:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#pic" ).click(function() {
        $( ".grid" ).resizable({
            grid: 20
        });
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

```
$(function() {
    $( ".grid" ).hide();
    $( "#pic" ).click(function(e) {
        $( ".grid" ).show();
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        $( ".grid" ).css('top', (e.clientX - offset.top) + 'px');
        $( ".grid" ).css('left', (e.clientY - offset.left) + 'px');
        $( ".grid" ).resizable({
            grid: 20
        });
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DW6Lc/19/)

Comment: i changed it, but when i click on my image, there is no grid displaying, ?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle to try your code please? @user2999787

Comment: Or he/she could just show us any errors in chrome developer tools by pressing F12 and navigating to the error section.

Comment: I have edit my answer, try to remove ; after grid value @user2999787

Comment: yes, i had to change to this: http://jsfiddle.net/DW6Lc/17/   the container with class=grid should be first displayed when click-event fired and exactly at this place i clicked. how to do this?

Comment: I edited my answer with the function that you want @user2999787

Answer (score 0):

Because you have used :

```
"#grid"
```

instead of:

```
".grid"
```

? You are trying to use `id` but in your html code you have declare `class` grid.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no element with id `grid`. `$('#grid')` is selector for element with `id = grid`, `$('.grid')` is selector for element with `class = grid`.